# files build execution order

Tags: c#, file, build

I have a data structure which is as given below:

```
 class File
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public File[] Dependencies { get; set; }
        public bool Change { get; private set; }
```

```
    public File(string value,File[] dependencies)
    {
        Value = value;
        Dependencies = dependencies;
        Change = false;
    }
}
```

Basically, this data structure follows a typical build execution of files.

Each File has a value and a list of dependencies which is again of type File. Every file is exposed with a property called Change which tells whether the file is changed or not.

I brainstormed to form a algorithm which goes through all these files and build in an order( i.e typical build process ) but haven't got a better algorithm.

Can anyone throw some light on this?

Thanks a lot.

Mahesh

Comment: You're asking for trouble creating a class that has the same name with a BCL class, `File`.  Use unique class names whenever possible and especially avoid common names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these basic steps.

1. Find files without any dependencies
2. Add those to the build first
3. Find files dependent on those in build and nothing else
4. Add those to build next
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until all files in build

You'll need some checks to detect circular dependencies which would cause and endless loop on step 5.  Other than that, this should work.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you are looking for is called [*topological sorting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).